# r Date conversion specific format

Tags: r

I have a date in POSIXlt format:

```
mydate
```

[1] "2011-12-25 15:47:21"

and I want a character string "12/25/2011"

I have tried using `"mydate$mon+1/mydate$mday/mydate$year+1900"` but I have problems making R evaluate the right terms.

Also, I tried `as.Date` with `format="%m/%d/%y"`  but it ignored that format and output

```
as.Date(mydate)
```

[1] "2011-12-25"

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi are you intending to achieve this?

```
 new <- as.POSIXlt("2011-12-25 15:47:21")
 format(new, format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 2):

I am going to put in a shameless self-plug for an R package I am developing, which will do this automatically. Version 0.0.1 is available here https://github.com/ramnathv/intellidate

```
library(intellidate)
new <- as.POSIXlt("2011-12-25 15:47:21")
str_to_date(new)

"2011-12-25"
```